# c= (getchar() != EOF)

Tags: c

I was trying to solve problem 1.6 in K&R.
The question is -

- Verify that the expression
  `getchar() != EOF` is 0 or 1.

I found a solution that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int expr_val, c;
   printf("Input a character and press enter: ");
   expr_val = (getchar() != EOF);
   printf("expr_val: %d\n", expr_val);

   return 0;
}
```

When I type in anything, it returns the value of 1. When I execute an EOF (Ctrl+D), it returns the value of 0.

However, when I replace the EOF in the code with a number, say 3, the program doesn't work as I expect it to. If I type in say, 5, it returns the value of 1. If I type in 3, it also returns the value of 1.

According to my understanding, typing in a value of 3 should return a value that is different than the value I get if I type in a value of 5.

(I only altered EOF into 3)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int expr_val, c;
   printf("Input a character and press enter: ");
   expr_val = (getchar() != 3);
   printf("expr_val: %d\n", expr_val);

   return 0;
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me on why this is the case?

---

Thank you everybody, your answers were all very clear and helpful. By changing the EOF to '3' or 51 the code worked properly.

Comment: `3` and `'3'` are different. See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for more info.

Comment: `expr_val = (getchar() != 'A');` and type`A`.

Comment: The K&R question is a bit silly, at least with respect to standard C.  The result of any relational operation (such as is performed by the `!=` operator) is either 0 or 1 by definition.

Answer (score 2):

You confuse integer and character.

`3` is not the character 3, but an integer. `'3'` is the character 3 in C.

Documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant).

Answer (score 2):

> `getchar()` function returns the character read as an unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.

So, you just need to change the comparison and use `'3'` (character '3') instead of `3` or you can use the ascii value of digit `3` which is 51. [see [ASCII Table]](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

```
expr_val = (getchar() != '3');
```

or,

```
expr_val = (getchar() != 51);
```

Now in both cases, you will get `expr_val = 0` if you type `3` as input.

Comment: C don't guarantee to use ASCII so `expr_val = (getchar() != 51);` is wrong. And magic number are a bad practice.

Comment: I agree, in that case do you want to suggest any alternative?

Comment: Why do you want alternative? `'3'` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

*(getchar() != 3)* is a **boolean** expression. 
Given this, your code will only assign a 0 or 1 to expr_val

Answer (score -1):

nobody explained how to convert '3' into 3. You use `atoi` https://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi or one of its cousins

Comment: `atoi` converts null-terminated strings. `'3'` would be converted to `3` by subtracting `'0'`. And OP does not need to do that conversion anyway.